# Анонимные (неименованые) каналы Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, c++

Здравствуйте.

Целью было создать программу с двумя потоками, которые обмениваются данными с помощью неименованых каналов.

Вот, почитал я про них, но все не то, везде описано создание процессов.

Вот что написал я.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

HANDLE Semf1;                      
DWORD dSize, ByteW, ByteR;
BOOL hPipe;

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFirst(LPVOID lpParam)
{

    char* StrOne = new char[50];
        std::cin>>StrOne;

    HANDLE rPipe=0, wPipe=0;     
    long p;
    dSize = 1024;

    hPipe = CreatePipe(&rPipe, &wPipe,NULL,dSize);

    ByteW=strlen(StrOne);

    wPipe = StrOne;
    hPipe = WriteFile(wPipe, StrOne, 20, &ByteW, NULL);

    ReleaseSemaphore(Semf1, 1, &p);
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadSecond(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(Semf1,INFINITE);

    HANDLE rPipe=0, wPipe=0;
    char* StrOne = new char[50];

    hPipe = ReadFile(rPipe, StrOne, 20, &ByteW, NULL);

    std::cout<<StrOne;

    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    DWORD dw;
    HANDLE hThread[2];

    Semf1 = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1, L"First");

    hThread[0] = CreateThread(NULL,0,ThreadFirst,0, 0, &dw);
    hThread[1] = CreateThread(NULL,0,ThreadSecond,0, 0, &dw);

    WaitForMultipleObjects(2,hThread,TRUE,INFINITE);

        system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор не ругается, но при выполнении если я ввел строку, ну скажем `qwerty`, то вывод будет пять знаков равно вместо введенных мною букв.

Вопрос. Что я делаю не так, да и вообще верной ли дорогой я пошел?

Comment: > using namespace std;  

>  std::cin  

?

Comment: Привычка, не заметил, но спс, исправлю)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У потоков `rPipe` и `wPipe` объявлены локально и второй поток не видит `pipe` созданный в первом. Во втором потоке `ReadFile` скорее всего возвращает ошибку, которую вы не обрабатываете. Объявите хэнделы пайпа глобально.

К тому же, зачем

```
 wPipe = StrOne;
```

Читать форумы по диагонали или читать msdn - что лучше?

Comment: Ну `wPipe = StrOne` согласен, мой оч большой косяк, потому как недочитал и недосмотрел как надо, торопился. Но все заработало, спасибо)